# AngularJS inner ng-repeat not processing $index.$parent in function argument

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Could someone more experienced than I explain to me why this compiles:

```
    <li class="btn dropdown top-stack breadcrumb-btn" ng-repeat="nodeName in selectedNodeNames">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle btn-anchor">{{nodeName}}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ng-class="activeState($parent.$index,$index)" ng-repeat="node in selectedNodeAtLevel($index).children">
                <a ng-click="tabSelect($parent.$index,$index)">{{getIndexString(node)}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

And the inner ng-repeat in this doesn't?

```
    <li class="btn dropdown top-stack breadcrumb-btn" ng-repeat="nodeName in selectedNodeNames">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle btn-anchor">{{nodeName}}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ng-class="activeState($parent.$index,$index)" ng-repeat="node in selectedNodeAtLevel($parent.$index).children">
                <a ng-click="tabSelect($parent.$index,$index)">{{getIndexString(node)}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Note that I am calling the selectedNodeAtLevel() function with $parent.$index, rather than just $index.  Why will it compile for the one and not the other?  And what can I do to achieve the same effect?

(By "compile" I mean that it does not generate any HTML, just a commented-out copy of the offending line)

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: The fact that the comment appears means that the code does compile (`ng-repeat` generates comments). I suspect the problem is with the data structure and that the function does not return what you expect in the second example. Can you post a demo? (jsfiddle or plnkr or similar)

Comment: The selectedNodeAtLevel function called with ($parent.$index) receives 'undefined' instead of a value. If I just stick ($index) in there, I get a value.  I'm wondering if the $parent value is not yet defined when the ng-repeat contents are evaluated?

Comment: Ah, I see what your question is.  I'll answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me point out that `ng-repeat` creates new scope.  Also, I'm assuming that the outer repeat does not sit inside yet another repeat.  Assuming that, notice in your first example that you pass `$index` to the `selectedNodeAtLevel` function. This works because `$index` is defined by the outer repeat and parsed in the context of the scope of the outer repeat. This `$index` variable corresponds to each `nodeName`.

So the second example fails because there is no `$index` defined in the outer repeat's `$parent` (which actually refers to the scope of the controller this code sits in).

In at least the second case, it seems that you expect that `$index` refers to the inner repeat, but it does not, it refers to the `$index` defined in the already defined scope.  So you should have issues even in your first example with `activeState` because of the reference there to `$parent.$index`.  Note that referring to `$index` from inside the inner repeat *will* refer to the `$index` on that inner scope.

Comment: You surmised precisely what I was intending.  Now that you've pointed it out it makes perfect sense.  Brilliant!